# SQL - Trigger that inserts data in to a table only if specific column have been updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger which will insert in to a table data only when specific column have been updated (not a whole table).

For example i have 2 tables called `tbl.A` and `tbl.A_History`:

tbl.A 
Have 5 columns: **id, name, location, age, gender**.

I would like to insert updated row to History only if location or name have been changed and do nothing if id, age, gender gets updated, removed, inserted.

Also i would like to be able to distinguish between location and name.

---

- If location changed insert `location have been changed`.
- If name changed insert `name have been changed`.

---

I have tried couple of thing but with no luck.

Comment: In which DB? Microsoft? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name ON tbl.A
FOR UPDATE
AS
IF ( UPDATE(location) OR UPDATE(name))
BEGIN
--  your sql here
END
```

Comment: try above query . in which trigger fires only when update operation performd on name or location column

Comment: Thanks that seems to do part of the job. And how do i insert different strings in to a variable based on which of them have been updated?

Comment: You mean add string to sql variable or some thing else.

Comment: Please note that UPDATE will return true if the column is in the update statement. Most of the time what people want is to know if the value actually changed. To determine that you would need to compare values from inserted and deleted.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER Test_Trg_01
ON Test
AFTER Update
AS
BEGIN
  IF update(name)
    INSERT INTO Test_Log SELECT id, 'name updated' AS LogMessage FROM inserted;

  IF update(country)
    INSERT INTO Test_Log SELECT id, 'country updated' AS LogMessage FROM inserted;
END
```

Comment: Please note that UPDATE will return true if the column is in the update statement. Most of the time what people want is to know if the value actually changed. To determine that you would need to compare values from inserted and deleted.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I forgot about this point... should be possible with something like this:

INSERT INTO Test_Log SELECT id, 'name updated' AS LogMessage
  FROM (SELECT ID, Name FROM inserted
        EXCEPT
  SELECT ID, Name FROM deleted) AS x;